# Interesting printf() glitch in C while converting bases

Tags: c

I have the following code in C:

```
char* getBase(unsigned int a, int base) {
    char buffer[33];

    char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    if(base < 2 || base > 16) {
        printf("Invalid base");
        return NULL;
    }

    char* cn = &buffer[sizeof(buffer) - 1];
    *cn = '\0';

    do {
        cn -= 1;
        *cn = digits[a % base];
        a /= base;
    } while(a > 0);

    printf("\n"); //HERE

    return cn;
}

int main() {
    printf("%s", getBase(8, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, it takes a base 10 number, and converts it to something between base 2 and base 16. It works UNLESS I comment out the line marked with `//HERE`. For some reason, if I don't have that printf statement, it doesn't work. I have no idea why this is happening, any explanations?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a automatic variable, it is undefined behavior. There must be a number of duplicates for this.

Comment: Yep. You're not allowed to return `buffer` because it only exists for the duration of `getBase`. Your compiler probably warned you about it.

Comment: try `static char buffer[33];`

Comment: Ah! `static char buffer[33];` fixed it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Undefined behavior could cause some quite weird behavior.

You are returning `cn` in the function `getBase`, which is a pointer that points to somewhere in the local automatic array `buffer`.

To fix the problem, you can make `buffer` static, or use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thank you for responding, how can I keep the memory pointed to by `cn` to be returned correctly?